# fileCopyOperation in fileOperations plugin throws the error - File Copy Operation: FATAL: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'D:/Test/ABC.pdf'

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Code:

```
fileOperations([fileCopyOperation(excludes: '', flattenFiles: true, 
includes: fullSrcFilePath, targetLocation: destFolderPath)])
```

Log:

```
Error:
File Copy Operation:
FATAL: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'D:/Test/ABC.pdf'
```

Are absolute paths not allowed in File Copy Operation?

I read a link where it says if I put a dir just above the call, it works. But that isn't ideal for my requirement. I'm trying to do file/folder operations in a loop by reading a config file.

Will someone please help out?

Answer (score 2):

You can write Windows paths with backslashes, but you have to escape them.

**Edit:** Indeed you can't put an absolute path in the `includes` argument.

```
def srcFileName = new File(fullSrcFilePath).name
def escapedSrcFolder = new File(fullSrcFilePath).getParent().replace('/', '\\\\')
def escapedDestFolderPath = destFolderPath.replace('/', '\\\\')
dir(escapedSrcFolder) {
    fileOperations([
        fileCopyOperation(
            flattenFiles: true,
            includes: srcFileName,
            targetLocation: escapedDestFolderPath
        )
    ])
}
```

**Edit #2:** If you get your pipeline from SCM you can't use the `File` methods, so for those cases you can use the following regexes:

```
def String getParent(String path) {
    path.replace('/', '\\') - ~/\\[^\\]+$/
}

def String getFileName(String path) {
    (path.replace('/', '\\') =~ /[^\\]+$/)[0]
}
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to work either... Gives the same error.

_File Copy Operation:
FATAL: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'D:\\Test\\ABC.pdf'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax_

Comment: Sorry I mislead you, I use `fileCopyOperation` a lot yet I overlooked absolute paths handling in my code. Fixed the answer.